# Average returning wrong value from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, average

I am trying to get an average of last 5 (non null) entries from my SQLite database. But somehow, Iam not getting the answer expected.

Heres the query

```
    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE "+FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE +" (" +
                            KEY_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                            KEY_KM + " LONG NOT NULL, "+
                            KEY_FUEL_QTY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "+
                            KEY_FUEL_PRICE + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "+
                            KEY_TOTAL_COST + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "+
                            KEY_MILEAGE + " DOUBLE NOT NULL, "+
                            KEY_DATE + " DATE NOT NULL, "+
                            KEY_TANK_FULL + " TEXT);"
                            );

    public long createEntry(FuelExpense fe) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_KM, fe.getKm());
            cv.put(KEY_FUEL_QTY, fe.getFuelQty());
            cv.put(KEY_FUEL_PRICE,fe.getFuelPrice());
            cv.put(KEY_TOTAL_COST, fe.getTotalCost());
            cv.put(KEY_MILEAGE, fe.getMileage());
            cv.put(KEY_DATE, fe.getFuelFilledDate());
            cv.put(KEY_TANK_FULL, fe.getTankFullstatus());
            return ourDatabase.insert(FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }





        public String getData()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_KM, KEY_FUEL_QTY, KEY_FUEL_PRICE, KEY_TOTAL_COST, KEY_MILEAGE, KEY_DATE,KEY_TANK_FULL};
            fuelCursor =  ourDatabase.query(FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            String resultSQL= "";

            while(fuelCursor.moveToNext())
            {
                resultSQL = resultSQL + fuelCursor.getString(0) + "         " + fuelCursor.getString(1) + "         " + fuelCursor.getString(2) +"           "+ fuelCursor.getString(3) + "          " + fuelCursor.getString(4) + "          " + fuelCursor.getString(5) + "         " + fuelCursor.getString(6) + "        " + fuelCursor.getString(7) + "\n ";  
            }
            return resultSQL;
        }
 public void getAvgMileage(Prediction pd) 
    {
            predictionCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT ROUND(AVG(_mileage)) FROM fuel_table WHERE _mileage IS NOT NULL ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 5", null);
                        if(predictionCursor!=null && predictionCursor.getCount()>0)
                        {
                                predictionCursor.moveToLast();
                                findAvgMileage = predictionCursor.getDouble(0);
                                pd.setpredictionMileage(findAvgMileage);

                        }

    The value obtained from predictionCursor needs to be used for further calculations like so,

            if(ETPredictFuelQty.hasFocus())
                        {
                            if(predictKm!=0)
                            {
                                predictFuetlQty =predictKm/predictionMileage;
                                ETPredictFuelQty.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(predictFuetlQty));
                            }

                        }
```

The _mileage has values 10,10,5,3.33,7.5 whose avg should be predictAvgMileage=7.166

I input values for predictKm =1000

SO predictFuelQty = predictKm/predictAvgMileage = 139.54 (Expected answer)

But Iam Getting predictFuelQty = 166.67

Can anybody help me find out whats wrong.
Also heres the SQL log

```
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ;
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(android_metadata);
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(sqlite_sequence);
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(fuel_table);
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index' 
SELECT rowid, *  FROM android_metadata ORDER BY rowid; 
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ;
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(android_metadata);
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(sqlite_sequence);
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(fuel_table);
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index' 
SELECT rowid, *  FROM android_metadata ORDER BY rowid; 
SELECT rowid, *  FROM fuel_table ORDER BY rowid;
```

Comment: How can you say it is not correct? What value it does return? what is the value you are expecting? What are the inputs?

Comment: @AAnkit I have added the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `LIMIT` clause applies to the *result* of the query, which is already a single record.
In other words, the query computes the average of all non-`NULL` records first, and *then* ensures that the `AVG` function does not return more than five values.

Try using a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(_mileage)
FROM (SELECT _mileage
      FROM fuel_table
      WHERE _mileage IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY _id DESC
      LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: That was the exact problem. Than you so much for the explanation as well. It was a great help. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're getting 166.67, I think you're actually getting 142.85 (142.86, I'm not sure how Java's `DecimalFormat` handles rounding and truncation).

Why would I think that? Well, your SQL says this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(_mileage)) ...
```

So the average is 7.166 and that becomes 7.0 when you round it. Then `1000/7.0` gives you `142.8571...`.

In any case, I think you just want to remove that `ROUND()` call from your SQL. And if you really are getting 166.67 then you'll want to check that your data really is what you think it is after the ORDER and LIMIT or look for a bug elsewhere in your computations.

Comment: Exactly, I tried and was getting 142.85.., And dint get how OP getting 162.67, There might be issue in her Table Schema or somewhere else in the computation, else it could have returned 142.***.

Comment: @AAnkit: I'm curious where they're getting the 6.0 from (`1000/6.0 == 166.6...`). I suspect the SQL isn't getting the data that they think it is getting and then the rounding just further confuses things.

Comment: Yes that is why I asked her to check all values in the database. I think this is the case, db is some how returning avg value as 6.0 :).
And she has not added even single log to confirm values.

Comment: @AAnkit yes! I checked the value in predictAvgMileage =6.0

Comment: Then go ahead and check why this value is not as expected. Print all values from database, see which value of mileage is wrong? See my answer and follow as suggested.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you so much for your time. There was a problem in my query. Thanks again for helping

Answer (score 1):

I would like more inputs from you.It will in terms tell you what is wrong here, if not I can be able to solve your issue.

1) Add your Table Schema in the question.( Most probably here is your issue)

2) just before you are trying to get avg from Database, try to get and print all the values available in the database. Print them, Add logs in the question.

3) print AVG value you are getting from DB.

```
findAvgMileage = predictionCursor.getDouble(0); // print findAvgMileage in the logs
```

add comment when done,so i can be notified.

P.S:- This is not the complete answer, due to length i could not able to add it as a comment. Would update answer as soon as OP update Question with more inputs

Comment: this is what i get from the predictCursor "findAvgMileage"=5.569285714285714

Comment: Now follow step 1 and 2 and your problem would vanish.:)

Comment: here I have added the code you asked for.. Pl see if its of any relevance.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. Realized with the help of the solution by CL there was a problem in my query. Thanks again for helping.